# twitter api max_id not working with get lists/statuses past certain date, but works with get statuses/usertimeline

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth

When I use max_id with GET statuses/user_timeline i am returned a tweet but when I use it with GET lists/statuses I get undefined.

```
var getIdTrump = {
    screen_name: "realdonaldtrump",
    count: 1,
    max_id: 756000000005000001
}

function getId() {
    T.get('statuses/user_timeline', getId, function (error, data) {
        console.log(error, data);
    })
}
// this code returns a tweet from 'Thu Jul 21 04:32:03 +0000 2016'
```

and this is the code that doesn't return a tweet (it returns undefined)

```
function retweetLatest() {
    var politician = {
        slug: "hillary-donald",
        owner_screen_name: "papipaulina",
        count: 1,
        include_rts: true,
        max_id: 756000000005000001
    };

    T.get('lists/statuses', politician, function (error, data) {
      console.log(error, data);
    });
}
```

However, the list that I am requesting from does return a tweet if the max_id is greater than 776000000005000001 ('Wed Sep 14 03:21:34 +0000 2016'). But i need to get about 2 months back and it wont let me.

(the list that I am working with includes the account that i am requesting the timeline from)

Comment: Usernames are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Usernames are case sensitive. Use capital letters where needed